# Why client authentication is NOT mandatory with Authorization Code Grant and Implicit Grant in OAuth2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0

According to RFC6749 Chapter 4.1.1: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.1
In the specification of Authorization Request for Authorization Code grant,
Only client_id is required for Authentication. Since client type could be public, then that means anyone can get the Authorization Code, and then use it in Access Token Request - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3. Here you only need to supply client_id (Which is public), Authorization Code (Which can obtain with NO authentication), redirect_uri and grant_type (Not for authentication/authorization purpose), and then you will be able to obtain an access token!

My question is, why **there is NO any mandatory authorization/authentication procedure for this type of grant, then what is the purpose of having this type of grant?** Same thing in Implicit grant.

Answer (score 1):

The client authentication is not mandatory only for the clients that are registered as public client like Mobile Native Application.  The Mobile Application can not hold client secret securely, hence it is not mandatory in authorization code grant and implicit grant.  The client application like web application which can hold client secret securely in the server, such clients should be registered as confidential client. The clients that are registered as confidential client should present both client id and secret for client authentication.

Comment: So for the public client, is the client id secure?

Answer (score 1):

OAuth2 server issues an authorization code after user authentication and after user approving consent with delegating rights to the client (identified by `client_id`). The auth code is then sent as a parameter to a client's registered redirect URI. So I don't know what you mean by *"anyone can get the Authorization Code"*.

Public clients should be used with [PKCE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636) OAuth2 extension. Which serves as a one-time password. So even if an auth code get stolen, it cannot be exchanged for tokens without knowing the `code_verifier` parameter of the token endpoint.

If an attacker creates a malicious application using someone else's client_id (pretending to be the client), the auth code will still be sent to the client's redirect URL. If the attacker gets hold of this URL handler, then it's probably a problem beyond the scope of the OAuth2 protocol.

Comment: OK, it sounds to me that, the authorization code grant, is not designed to protect the resource? Otherwise, for a public client, let's say application A registered and set the redirect uri. Once Application B got the id, and even its still redirect to the pre-registered uri, Application B still can act as Application A and do whatever AppA can do?

Comment: AppB can initiate the same `/auth` request as AppA, but the resulting auth code will be sent to a redirect URL controlled by AppA (such as `https://appA.com/auth?code=abc123`). So AppB will not get the code. If it doesn't answer you question, please consider updating it with a concrete example - numbered steps where OAuth2 fails.

Comment: But still, even AppB did not get the code directly, request redirected to https://appA.com/auth?code=abc123, from that point AppB still can get the access token? As there is no any other authentication procedure?
Or, let's put it this way: AppA and AppB both run and go through all the procedures and finally, anything AppA can get, AppB can too. What is the different?

Comment: I probably don't understand what you mean. If AppB doesn't get the code, it cannot exchange it for an access token either. AppB cannot read the code from the AppA's URL.

Comment: Well I think I'd better understand what do you mean by send the code by uri mean.
Q1: where does App run to get the redirect uri? resource server, or client?
Q2: If App run on client machine, that means AppA and AppB can run on the same machine, No matter what the grant procedure is, what is the difference regarding getting resources from server, if they all know the public client id?

Comment: Oh, let's say, what thing that AppA can do with just a public id but AppB CANNOT do? If all application can do, then what is the code trying to protect?

Comment: Redirect URIs are registered at the OAuth2 server for each OAuth2 client (application). Both AppA and AppB have client roles. AppB cannot change a redirect URI of AppA client. Even if they run on the same machine, only one of them can handle a given redirect URI. If you use AppA's client_id for an auth request, you must use one of AppA's registered redirect URIs. If you mean getting resources from a resource server, you need an access token for it with some scopes. As I wrote before, it would be much easier to disccuss concrete steps (who does what in what sequence).